# Мне нужно вывести нечетные числа в промежутке через пробел, но без пробела в конце, как это сделать?

Tags: python-3.x

```
a,b=map(int,input().split())
for i in range(a,b+1):
    if i%2!=0:
        print(i, end=" ")
```

У меня вот такое решение, но нужно убрать пробел в конце

Answer (score 2):

Ну как-нибудь вот так, через `join`. Зато еще потом все эти числа можно использовать будет.

```
a, b=map(int,input().split())
list_nums = []
for i in range(a,b+1):
    if i%2!=0:
        list_nums.append(i)
print(' '.join(map(str, list_nums)))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Распечатать можно одной строчкой:

```
print(*(i for i in range(a,b+1) if i%2))
```

Comment: это чере таб...

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> a + 1 - a % 2 = a + 1 если `a` чётное
> a + 1 - a % 2 = a     если `a` нечётное
> следовательно
> a + 1 - a % 2 - наименьшее нечётное число большее или равное a
> ```

Тогда все нужные числа можно получить одним вызовом [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range):

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
print(*range(a + 1 - a % 2, b + 1, 2))
```